# ERROR: attempt to redefine parameter "postgis.backend"

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I just install "SFCGAL". When I use "ST_3DIntersection", It get below error:

ERROR: attempt to redefine parameter "postgis.backend" SQL state: XX000

How can I fix?

I already saw http://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html, But I do not know how should I do.

Comment: I also alter my database backend with follow code, but I get this error, yet.
ALTER DATABASE mygisdb SET postgis.backend = sfcgal;

Comment: Please [do not cross-post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/132567). It wastes everyone's time duplicating follow-up questions and replies.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you installed the SFCGAL extension in your PostGIS 2.1 db instead of a PostGIS 2.2 db.

If so, you need to upgrade your PostGIS to PostGIS 2.2 with the alter extension.

```
ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE TO "2.2.0dev";
```

The issue I suspect you are running into is because you have two versions of PostGIS -- SFGCAL loads up the postgis-2.2.dll and your regular postgis loads postgis-2.1.dll

Both define the postgis.backend GUC so can't coexist together.  You should never mix these.

Comment: Reza, did you resolve the problem or are you still having problems

Comment: @LR1234567-I solve it by run above code, TNX.